# syntax error, ';' expected but 'until' found

Tags: pascal

I have a problem with my Pascal code.
There is some error and I don´t know where.

```
program GTA6;

uses
  Crt;

var
  obraz, x, mampistoli, mamnuz: Integer;
begin
  clrscr;
  randomize;
  obraz := 1;

  repeat
    clrscr;
    if obraz = 1 then
    begin
      writeln('Je 9:00 rano. Probudis se ve svem byte. Nekdo ti zvoni na dvere. Pujdes otevrit(2) nebo budes zvonek ignorovat(3)?');
      readln(obraz);
      if (obraz <> 2) and (obraz <> 3) then
        obraz := 1;
    end
    else
    if obraz = 2 then
    begin
      writeln('Otevres dvere a jsou tam dva dvoumetrovy plesaty chlapi s pistolema v ruce. Prej dluzis jejich sefoj 200 000 Kc a chce je vratit do 19:00 jinak te prijdou zabit.');
      writeln('  Sahnout po pistoli(4), nedelat nic (5)');
      readln(obraz);
      if (obraz <> 2) and (obraz <> 3) and (obraz <> 4) and (obraz<> 5) then
        obraz := 2;
    end
    else
    if obraz = 5 then
    begin
      if mampistoli <> 1 then
      begin
        writeln('Odesli. Ty zjistis, ze nemas 200 000.');
        writeln('vzit si pistoli(1), nebo si vzit nuz(2)');
        readln(x);
        if x = 1 then
          mampistoli := 1;
        if x = 2 then
          mamnuz := 1;
      end;
      writeln('Takhle narychlo tolik penez nesezenes...budes muset udelat banku, nebo tak neco.');
      writeln('Vyloupit banku (6), trafiku (7), vykr st auto (8)');
      readln(obraz);
      if (obraz <> 6) and (obraz <> 7) and (obraz <> 8) then
        obraz := 5;
    end
    else
    if obraz = 6 then
    begin
      if mampistoli = 1 then
      begin
        writeln('Rozhodl jsi se vyloupit banku s pistoli.');
        writeln('Hlidac videl tvoji zbran a vystrelil po tobe!');
        x := random(100);
        if x < 50 then
          writeln('Trefil te primo do hlavy!');
        writeln('Zemrel jsi!');
        obraz := 0;
      end;
    until obraz = 0;

  writeln('KONEC HRY');
  if x > 50 then
    writeln('Netrefil se!');
  readln;
end.
```

where is problem?

Comment: please format your code when you're asking other people to look at it. edit your post to take out all that whitespace, and indent it so it's easy to read.

Comment: Try to learn how to use `case` statement. It will simplify your spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `end;` before the `until` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `end;` for one of the `if` statements.

You have these two `if` statements beginning a code block:

```
end else if obraz=6 then begin
  if mampistoli=1 then begin
```

but there is only one `end;` to end them.

If you indent your code carefully, it is easier to spot problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
repeat
...
    end else if obraz=6 then
    begin
        if mampistoli=1 then 
        begin
            writeln('Rozhodl jsi se vyloupit banku s pistoli.');
        writeln('Hlidac videl tvoji zbran a vystrelil po tobe!');
        x:=random(100);
        if x< 50 then writeln('Trefil te primo do hlavy!');
            writeln('Zemrel jsi!');
        obraz:=0;
        end;
    END; <---
until obraz=0;
```

Comment: http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Styl_z%C3%A1pisu_programu
podivej se jak zarovnavat kod - begin a end na stejne urovni.

 Indent is a base for your programming, especially in pascal.

Comment: :D you are right - I made this "wrong indet" only to find where is mistake.
I hope it is ok now :)